# MySQL IF Condition in Where Clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

Is it possible to decide by IF Condition which Where Clause I want to choose.

Something like:

```sql
IF(DATE_FORMAT(DATE(akDate), '%a')='SAT', USE WHERECLAUSE1, USE WHERECLAUSE2)
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. What you might do is the opposite: move the IF into the WHERE clause - it's a bit unclear to me, however, what is the end goal you're trying to reach.

Comment: Please provide sample where clauses and we can show you how they may be combined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the case you can still write using rather common `WHERE` statement such as this:

```
... WHERE
(
    (DATE_FORMAT(DATE(akDate), '%a') = 'SAT')
    AND
    (WHERECLAUSE1)
)
OR
(
    (DATE_FORMAT(DATE(akDate), '%a') != 'SAT')
    AND
    (WHERECLAUSE2)
)
```

where, of course, you should replace `WHERECLAUSE1` and `WHERECLAUSE2` with appropriate conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Easy, you should read on [Boolean Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). In your case, here we go:

```
A = WhereClause1
B = WhereClause2
X = Choice
```

You need to select lines with `X && A` OR lines with `!X && B`. So basically your expression will be: `(X && A) || (!X && B)`. Which leads to:

```
(
    (Choice AND WhereClause1) 
    OR 
    ((NOT Choice) AND WhereClause2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query  = " SELECT apt.apt_id,apt.reg_id,apt.u_id,apt.b_id,apt.apt_bathroom,apt.apt_size,apt.apt_rent,apt.apt_desc,apt.negotiable,apt.apt_status,apt.govt_program,building.b_borough,building.b_zipcode,building.b_type,building.b_intersection,building.b_intersection2,building.b_desc FROM apt LEFT JOIN building ON apt.b_id = building.b_id WHERE apt.apt_status = 1 AND ";
if ($search_size != 'empty')
{
    $query .= "apt.apt_size = '".$search_size."' ";
    if ($search_borough != 'empty' || $search_zipcode != 'empty' )
        {
            $query .= " AND ";
        }
}
if ($search_borough != 'empty')
{
    $query .= "building.b_borough= '".$search_borough."' ";
    if ($search_zipcode != 'empty')
        {
            $query .= " AND ";
        }
}
if ($search_zipcode != 'empty')
{
    $query .= "building.b_zipcode = '".$search_zipcode."' ";
}
$query .= "ORDER BY apt.apt_id DESC LIMIT $start,$perpage ";

$query_run = mysql_query ($query);
if (!$query_run)
{
    echo 'Error In the Query limit.';
}
```